# Get PID of last executed command (NO BACKGROUND)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pid

I want to know the PID of the last executed command.
I saw this a lot:

```
$ command &
$ pid=$!
```

But I'm searching for the same thing without running the command in the background.

Comment: But if you won't run it in the background, the execution will not continue untill it exits. The PID will be useless then. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Sounds logical. I thought it could be usefull couse my command is a call to another script.
I'll give it a try!

Comment: @BłażejMichalik, I forgot to exit my functions in the other script.
Thanks!

Comment: @BłażejMichalik `command` may be a process group leader which spawn subprocesses in the background, and the remainder of the script may need to send signals to the subprocesses once `command` exits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following construction in scripts:

```
PID=`sh -c "echo $$; exec your_command -with-arguments"`
echo $PID
```

Comment: I use this for starting my_commmand with -daemon options, but I think if you need output you can use something like `sh -c "echo $$ <super-separator-field>; exec your_command -with-arguments"` ans use awk or grep